# Same Image is showing in modal from Image list whille click on Image

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

I have made modal for showing large image on click on Image from Image list. But it is showing same image same time on click of any image.

**Currently I am getting Same image on every click on Image**

**I want to see different image which I click on Image.**

My code is look like this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($attachment)){
    ?>

    <tr id='ea<?php echo $row['enquiry_attachment_id'];?>'>
        <th><?php 
            $ext = pathinfo($row['file_name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg','jpeg');
            if(in_array(strtolower($ext),$allowed) ) {
                echo "
                <div class='pop'>
                <image class='imageresource' id='imageresource'  src='assets/enq_attachment/".$row['file_name']."' style='width:100px;height:100px'>
                </div>
                ";
            }else{
                if($ext == "pdf"){
                    echo "<i class='fa fa-file-pdf-o'></i>";
                }else if($ext == "xls" || $ext == "xlsx" || $ext == "csv"){
                    echo "<i class='fa fa-file-excel-o'></i>";
                }else{
                    echo $row['file_name'];
                }
            }


        ?></th>
        <td><a href="assets/enq_attachment/<?php echo $row['file_name'];?>" target='_blank'>DOWNLOAD</a></td>
        <td><span class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteFun('enquiry_attachment',<?php echo $row['enquiry_attachment_id'];?>,'ea<?php echo $row['enquiry_attachment_id'];?>')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> </span></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $number = $number + 1;
}
```

Modal look like this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <img src="" id="imagepreview" class="imagepreview" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;" >
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Js code look like this

```
 $(function() {

    $('.pop').on('click', function() {
        $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $('.imageresource').attr('src'));
        $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
    });     
});
```

Comment: Can you add  $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $('.imageresource').attr('src')+"?key="+Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)+");

Comment: You are using a duplicate ID in the loop. Every element that has an id attribute MUST have a unique ID ~ ie: `imageresource` being the duplicated ID

Comment: You also should not mix `th` and `td` in the same row

Comment: How can I make unique ID ? and How to take ID in JS ? @RamRaider

Comment: Assuming that in addition to duplicated IDs there are actually multiple images with class `imageresource` how would the javascript function know which one it is to find? It needs to reference the child node ( don't use jQuery so can't help but I know jQuery has methods for `find`ing elements )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I say I don't use jQuery but I think essentially what is happening with your code is that the event listener needs to refer to the element that receives the `click` event and then find the child node ~ `img.imageresource`

Incidentally I forgot to say, the tag should be `img` rather than `image`

```
 $(function() {
    $('.pop').on('click', function() {


        /* or should that be $( this ) ?? */

        let child=this.querySelector('img.imageresource')
        $('.imagepreview').attr( 'src', child.src );


        $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
    });     
});
```

Comment: excellent! I'm sure you could tidy that up to use `jQuery` specific methods if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for pure `jquery` based solution then you could use following code

```
    $('.pop').on('click', function() {
        var imgSrc = $(this).children('.imageresource').attr('src'); //get image src here
        $('.imagepreview').attr('src', imgSrc );
        $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
    });
```